# Moderator agreement still refers to Stack Exchange Inc

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-exchange, wording

The moderator agreement is visible at the following URL:

https://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement

> I acknowledge and agree that as a moderator for Stack Exchange Inc.
>
> I will abide by the then-current Terms of Service of Meta Stack
>   Exchange, and other moderator policies made available to me,
>
> I acknowledge that I may have access to potentially
>   personally-identifying information about Meta Stack Exchange users and
>   that in connection with such access
>
> I will use such information solely in accordance with the then-current
>   Privacy Policy of Meta Stack Exchange,
>
> I will not disclose this information to anyone,
>
> I will not store or copy this information and
>
> I will only use such information in connection with performance as a
>   Meta Stack Exchange moderator for the benefit of Meta Stack Exchange.
>
> I acknowledge and agree that I am an independent volunteer moderator
>   to Meta Stack Exchange and I am not an employee, agent or
>   representative of Stack Exchange Inc., and I have no authority to bind
>   Stack Exchange Inc. in any manner. Stack Exchange Inc. reserves the
>   right to terminate my privileges as a moderator at any time without
>   warning.

It hasn't been updated with the new company name and still refers to Stack Exchange Inc. instead of Stack Overflow (Inc.?).

Comment: I'm not sure that anything's actually been updated to reflect the new name yet, for that matter. TOS, footers, [/about](http://stackexchange.com/about).

Comment: …They also (seemingly) haven't reincorporated as Stack Overflow, Inc. Maybe the name change is purely cosmetic, in which case the agreement would still be with the legal entity? I have no idea how that works. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Stack Overflow is a "DBA" (doing business as). The legal name for the company is not changing.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young This is getting even more confusing than it already was

Comment: @MadScientist Not really. For example, the company behind OkCupid (at least before its acquisition by IAC) is Humor Rainbow, Inc. But most people just know the company as OkCupid.

Comment: @MadScientist Another example, [Harvest](http://www.getharvest.com/) is run by a company called Iridesco, but most people just call them Harvest. Similarly, in our case, so many people just call us Stack Overflow, that we decided to adopt that as our primary brand.

Comment: @Chris think it's worth an answer with all the details you gave in comments. :-)

Comment: Guess there are too many bugs to fix, so took the comments and posted them as answer myself.

Comment: @Chris I don't think it says the DBA thing in the blog post - any chance of that being added? Because it's actually quite important!

Comment: @Chris also, would it be wrong to just think of stack overflow as, basically, an "alias"?

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ I *think* that Stack Overflow is now the "legal" name, used for tax and billing etc, while Stack Exchange is still the actual name being commonly known. (Of course, might be way off base :))

Comment: @ShadowWizard It might be the other way round, as Chris said `The legal name for the company is not changing`...?

Comment: Voting to close as dupe of similar "bug", with official response.

Answer (score 3):

As SE employee [Chris Jester-Young](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/13/chris-jester-young) says in the comments on this question:

> Stack Overflow is a "DBA" (doing business as). The legal name for the company is not changing. <sub>[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266880/moderator-agreement-still-refers-to-stack-exchange-inc#comment866670_266880)</sub>

He also brings couple of examples:

> 1. The company behind OkCupid (at least before its acquisition by IAC) is Humor Rainbow, Inc. But most people just know the company as OkCupid <sub>[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266880/moderator-agreement-still-refers-to-stack-exchange-inc#comment866672_266880)</sub>
> 2. [Harvest](http://www.getharvest.com/) is run by a company called Iridesco, but most people just call them Harvest. <sub>[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266880/moderator-agreement-still-refers-to-stack-exchange-inc#comment866674_266880)</sub>

And to conclude:

> Similarly, in our case, so many people just call us Stack Overflow, that we decided to adopt that as our primary brand. <sub>[source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266880/moderator-agreement-still-refers-to-stack-exchange-inc#comment866674_266880)</sub>

Comment: Sorry for coming to the party so late (but I was reading the new legal policy documents, and that made me itch, so I’m scratching here). This doesn’t pass the smell test. I suppose I should say that this makes [the famous / infamous blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2015/09/15/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow "We’re Changing Our Name (Back) to Stack Overflow") smell bad, inasmuch as it says “tl;dr – We’re changing our company name.” and “As of today, our company will be known as Stack Overflow.” … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  No mention of [“brand / trade name”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270037/195817#270038 "from an answer by Oded"); no mention of “DBA (doing business as)”; no mention of “Stack Exchange, Inc.”  We’re allowed to edit questions and answers to clarify them; why can’t somebody edit the blog post to include this information?