# Trademark Guidance Page: "The Stack Exchange Blog"

Tags: discussion, feature-request, stackexchange.com, legal

Under the "Proper Use of the Stack Exchange Name" section on https://stackexchange.com/legal/trademark-guidance, it says (last bullet):

> The **Stack Exchange Blog** is the company blog which talks about everything we're doing on all our sites and what the company itself is doing.

However after the rename, the URL was changed to `blog.stackoverflow.com` **and** the title of the page is `Stack Overflow Blog`.

So should the `Stack Exchange Blog` be changed to `Stack Overflow Blog`?

Now, nobody really knows what the name change really means :P but can *something* be changed? To make it more consistent: either the title of the blog or the trademark guidance page. :)

Comment: I suppose it will change in 6-8 weeks ;)

Answer (score 2):

> **We’re changing our company name**

...

> In the weeks ahead, we’ll change the name of things like the blog, podcast, and any other places where “Stack Exchange” was referring to the company, as opposed to the network of Q&A sites.

Source [We are Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2015/09/were-changing-our-name-back-to-stack-overflow/)

Comment: But the thing is that some places, where *we* would think it should be changed, SE/SO (?) don't, as seen [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266880/260841). I'm posting this question because either way, *something* needs to change - either the blog or the guidance page...