# Difference between Stack Exchange and Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, support

I am new to Meta stack Exchange.

I don't know the difference between **Stack Exchange** and **Stack Overflow**.

I have been using **Stack Overflow** for more than 2 years. I know SO is for programming related questions. But what is the purpose of **Stack Exchange**?

Comment: This site also has a [tour] and a [help].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as you know Stack Overflow is for programming related stuff.

**Stack Exchange** is the network consist of many sites like Stack Overflow each of them designed for specific purpose like

- Super user
- Android SE
- Travel SE

and more than 169 sites are there

Stack Overflow is created first and Stack Exchange came later.

<sup>*To confuse you, Stack Overflow is the father and eldest son of Stack Exchange*</sup>

Comment: slightly relevant: Stack Overflow is the company .. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266410/how-to-refer-to-stack-exchange-the-company-after-its-rename-to-stack-overflow

Comment: yeah thanks for information rene. my first edit made it worse. Corrected.