# Why are Stack Exchange profile deletion email notifications sent from Stack Overflow email address?

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, email

I deleted my AcademiaSE profile, and nearly had a heart attack [image: when I received a confirmation email from Stack Overflow] (do-not-reply@stackoverflow.email) with a subject line of "Your profile has been deleted".

Why is this notification sent from an email address that appears to be for another site on the network?

Comment: [so] is the company.

Comment: @redhand But why does Stack Overflow have its own email, but not the other networks?

Comment: That's what I answered. Stack Exchange is not the company. Stack Overflow is the company. So, they registered a domain  with the company name

Comment: Perhaps it would help if they changed the subject to "Your profile on Foo Stack Exchange has been deleted"?

Comment: @yannis That would at least be a start. Often the first thing someone sees when notified of an email (particularly on mobile, at least for me) is the sender though, and I feel like it's weird to send an email about an SE site from an address that looks like another SE site.

Comment: why should they? there is some meta post regarding it. I can't find it atm.

Comment: We might want to add [the originating email address in the announcement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300185/158100)

Comment: wrt to SE,Inc vs SO,Inc: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266410/158100 they don't seem to be utterly clear or consistent about it as well. The answer there reads to me as; *use SO or SE at your convenience*.

Comment: @GoatsWearHats It's not about buying 2 domains, we'd have to buy many more than that, Ask Ubuntu, Math Overflow, Super User, Server Fault, Stack Apps, and Stack Exchange `.email` domains. Then we'd need certificates for all of them. And we'd need IPs or aliases for them. And DMARC support. And reputation monitoring. And we'd have to build into the entire system what to send from where. These added up are significantly more than "just buying another domain". Not that it helps much, but I wanted to illustrate the scale of the simple fix implied here...because it's not simple.

Comment: One more note: bear in mind when people want to whitelist our email address so they always get it, we'd be asking **users** to whitelist 7 domains (so far), not just one. That's cost put on users, not us. That is something we very actively try to avoid.

Comment: Might be a simpler matter of changing the sender's name (not the email address) to the site in question? That's entirely arbitrary as far as I remember-  so "Acedemia.se<do-not-reply@....>

Comment: Changing the subject line to insert the specific site seems easiest.  Changing the sender name (not email address) would also work; I don't know how hard that is.  We don't need to change the actual email address and, as Nick said, we want people to be able to easily whitelist SE.

Answer (score 13):

For the reasons outlined by Nick Craver in comments to the question, we will not change the from address of the email, namely:

- it is not a simple change, as some people think
- it will make it difficult to whitelist all SE emails

We have updated the subject line of the emails to include the community name - so this should alleviate such concerns in the future.